# How do I 'save as' with a placed file's name in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, save

Say I have a file `DSC_0377.jpg`. I can open a this with Illustrator, make
changes, then choose <kbd>File</kbd> <kbd>Save As</kbd> <kbd>Save as type</kbd>
<kbd>Adobe PDF</kbd>

and it will be saved as `DSC_0377.pdf`, as desired. However if I

- open an Illustrator Template
- <kbd>File</kbd> <kbd>Place</kbd> the same JPG
- <kbd>File</kbd> <kbd>Save As</kbd> <kbd>Save as type</kbd>
  <kbd>Adobe PDF</kbd>

it will be saved as `Untitled-1.pdf`. Does Illustrator have an easy way to save
using the name of the placed file? I have many JPGs I need to do this with, so I
would prefer to not have to do something like copy and paste the file names.

Comment: This is really more of an Illustrator user question rather than a graphic design question. But it comes down to using an Illustrator Template file which defaults to "Untitled" when saved since it's assumed you will want to name the file differently than the Template file name.

Comment: What is your objective? is it to convert JPG's to PDF's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Template in this case is really just a single Compound Shape. So to work
around this problem I used this workflow:

1. Open Template
2. Open JPG normally, not using Place
3. Copy Shape to JPG
4. Save as PDF

After that I just leave the Template tab open, and open other JPGs to repeat.